# CIRCLECI echo to file gives permission error

Tags: bash, continuous-integration, travis-ci, continuous-deployment, circleci

I'm trying to write the content of variable $NAME into a file whose name is
$VERSION_FILE

but on doing

```
echo $NAME > "$VERSION_FILE"
```

works in locally, in circleci I get:

```
cannot create /version: Permission denied
```

and subsequent commands fail too

```
head: cannot open '/version' for reading: No such file or directory
```

Comment: You say it works on the command line, but not from a daemon? A problem with SELinux?

Comment: Does circleci run as `root`?  `/version` would be in the `/` directory an typically only root can operate in there.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using the root user (I can't tell from your example), then prefix the command with `sudo`.